# Is it possible to save the output from a write command in a file? (API and Powershell)

Tags: powershell, api, openweathermap

i just started with Powershell and have already a problem.
I am using the API from OpenWeathermap (https://openweathermap.org/) to create something like a weather-bot.

I am using this function from the API:

```
Write-WeatherCurrent -City $place -ApiKey $ApiKey -Units metric
```

Where the Output something like this (if I fill the Variables):
10.2°C (☁️ few clouds) in london

So I want this Output to save in a File. I already tried with the Commands Out-File and >>. But it only outputs in the Terminal and the File is empty. I am not sure, but is it because of "Write"-WeatherCurrent?

I would be happy if anybody could help me :D

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Write-WeatherCurrent` uses `Write-Host`](https://github.com/kamranayub/posh-openweathermap/blob/master/OpenWeatherMap.psm1#L250-L269) to write the output directly to the host console buffer.

If you're using PowerShell 5.0 or newer, you can capture the `Write-Host` output to a variable with the `InformationVariable` common parameter:

```
Write-WeatherCurrent -City $place -ApiKey $ApiKey -Units metric -InformationVariable weatherInfo
```

`$weatherInfo` now contains the string output and you can write it to file:

```
$weatherInfo |Out-File path\to\file.txt
```

If the target command doesn't expose common parameters, another option is to merge the `Information` stream into the standard output stream:

```
$weatherInfo = Write-WeatherCurrent -City $place -ApiKey $ApiKey -Units metric 6>&1 # "stream 6" is the Information stream
```

Comment: @Searching.... you should only pass the _name_ of the target variable, so it's `-InformationVariable weatherInfo`, not `-InformationVariable $weatherInfo` (no `$`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it still doesnt work. The output still is written on the host console buffer but the file and the variables are empty.

Comment: Just did it but it doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: @Searching.... Have you tried copy-pasting the command from my answer and running it as-is? The output is still expected to be written to the console and then _also_ copied to the variable specified by name. If it still doesn't work, can you share which version of PowerShell you're using? `"$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"`

Comment: i copied it as-is, still doesnt work. Could I send you the whole Code? And its 5.1

Comment: @Searching.... Updated the answer with an alternative for when the target command doesn't expose `-InformationVariable`, give it a try :)

Comment: IT WORKED, but in the file its not on one line. Is it possible to get the whole output on one line?

Comment: @Searching.... Excellent news! You could try `-join($weatherInfo) |Out-File ...` or `$weatherInfo -join '' |Out-File ...` :)

Comment: One more question if I get more then one output back like: 
Oct 21: 14.745°C (☁️ few clouds)
Oct 22: 10°C (️ light rain)
Oct 23: 7.13°C (☁️ broken clouds)
Oct 24: 7.86°C (☀️ clear sky)
It only saves the first one. You know why and how to fix it?
Its like listed one under another

Comment: If you want to execute multiple statements and capture the information stream from all, wrap them in a block like this: `&{ Write-WeatherCurrent ...; Write-WeatherForecast ... } 6>&1`